# Radio button in iPhone app

Tags: iphone

I have to add radio buttons in my iPhone application. For that I have got radio button image which is of round in shape. Can I add that image as a subview? and Can I add touchupinside event to UIImage?

Comment: I tried what you said, It works fine. Initially the button looks like a round button, but the moment the button is clicked, the frame of the button appears(looks like a square button)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

iPhone apps do not have radio buttons.  The "iPhone-like" way to do this is either by using a picker view or by having several rows in a grouped table view with a check accessory on the chosen row.

If for some reason you really, really feel the need to have radio buttons, use a UIButton with a button type of custom.  Set the empty circle as the image for the "normal" control state and the filled circle as the image for the "selected" state.

Comment: I tried what you said, It works fine. Initially the button looks like a round button, but the moment the button is clicked, the frame of the button appears(looks like a square button)

Comment: How Can I get rid of this thing?

Comment: If this one is not doable, the I have to try something else. So please tell me whether getting rid of this behavior is possible

Comment: You need to change the image for the Highlighted state as well.  It should probably be a variant of the Selected button which suggests that you're in the middle of pressing the button.

Comment: To back up Brent's point on this answer, see Apple's iOS Human Interface Guidelines here, where they recommend against using radio buttons in favor of lists, pickers, or switch controls: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/HandleTasks/HandleTasks.html

Answer (score 5):

Try [UISegmentedControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006807). It behaves similarly to radio buttons -- presents an array of choices and lets the user pick 1.

Comment: do you know how UISegmentedControl can be created in Titanium?

Answer (score 2):

```
IBOutlet UIButton *checkboxButtonMale; 

IBOutlet UIButton    *checkboxButtonFmale;

  checkboxButtonFmale.tag = 3;
  checkboxButtonMale.tag = 2; 

(IBAction)checkboxGenderChecked:(id)sender{ 


    UIButton *selectedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    UIButton    *toggledButton; 

    if (selectedButton.tag == 2 ) { 
        toggledButton =    checkboxButtonFmale;
    } 
    else {      
        toggledButton = checkboxButtonMale; 
    }   [toggledButton    setSelected:NO]; 
    [sender setSelected:YES];
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a UIWebView, load into it HTML that uses radio buttons, and then using the UIWebView delegat methods, monitor the radio value.

It's kind of a hack, but in some cases it's exactly what's called for.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array of `UIButton`s, then use my [GSRadioButtonSetController](https://github.com/goosoftware/GSRadioButtonSetController) class to handle the logic (essentially, ensuring that only one button can be selected). See the README on GitHub for sample usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the UIImageView class which just wraps a UIImage inside a UIView container. It supports the touchesBegan/Cancelled events which would be suitable I think.

You might also consider not using with a true radio button setup as you've described and instead going with a more iPhone-like approach--for instance, using a UITableView with cells corresponding to your radio selections and that toggle checked/unchecked on a touch. See the TouchCells example at the Apple iPhone dev site for an example.

Comment: I have created my radio button class by extending UIButton class, in my radiobutton class, how can I set the buttontype to UIButtonTypeCustom?.

Comment: Custom is the default button type.

Comment: Hi drewh, Finally I did what you suggested. I used UIImageView class and touchesBegan event. It works fine with no issues. Thanks a lot.  Thanks to Brent too for giving me ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only "yes" or "no" options then use UISwitch.

For multiple type use the code below:

```
-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender{

if([sender isSelectd])

//here change button image and set

[sender setSelected:NO];

}else{
//here change button image and set

[sender setSelected:YES];

}
```

remember, when you create the button don't forget to set the setSelected to NO.

Answer (score 0):

There is no any RadioButton control in iPhone application.

Though you can check folliwing link for taking RadioButton.

Here we placed Two Images in place of RadioButtons.

http://www.developers-life.com/radio-buttons-in-iphone-application.html

Enjoy Coding........

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this and it works:

```
- (IBAction)tickbuttonClicked:(id)sender
{

UIButton *selectedButton = sender;
UIImage *ticked   = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tickbox_yes3.png"];   
UIImage *unticked = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tickbox_no3.png"];    

    //untick active box
    if((activetag>-1)&&(activetag!=[sender tag])){
        UIButton *thisButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:activetag];
        thisButton.backgroundColor  = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:unticked];
    }

 //tick sender
 if ([sender tag]!=activetag)
 {
    selectedButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:ticked]; 
    activetag=[sender tag];   
    [selectedButton setSelected:YES];

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

//define property of button

**Declare Unchaked Image**

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
   {
       [ButtonChaked setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UnChacked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

**Chaked Image**.

```
 - (IBAction)ButtonChaked:(id)sender
 {
    if (ButtonChaked.selected ==YES)
    {
      [ButtonChaked setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UnChacked.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    ButtonChaked.selected =NO;

 }
 else
 {
    [ButtonChaked setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Chaked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    ButtonChaked.selected = YES;

 }


}
```

that's really used

Answer (score 0):

I just published an iOS Radio Button control to Cocoapods `pod "DLRadioButton"`, for documentation and examples, please go to [GitHub](https://github.com/DavydLiu/DLRadioButton). Attached are screenshots for this control.[image]