# How to create a round button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to create a round circular button. This button should look like  a circle.

This code gives round rectangular button.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame     = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 30);
UIImage  *image  = [UIImage imageNamed:@"01.png"];
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[image release];
```

I figured out how to create a rounded rectangular button but I want to create a round circle button. What do I need to change?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Round UIButton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666080/round-uibutton)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

**Tested Code:**

.h

```
 #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

-(void)roundButtonDidTap:(UIButton*)tappedButton;
```

.m

```
#define ROUND_BUTTON_WIDTH_HEIGHT YourButtonWidthToBeSetHere

-(void)roundButtonDidTap:(UIButton*)tappedButton{

    NSLog(@"roundButtonDidTap Method Called");

}



UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TimoonPumba.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(roundButtonDidTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

//width and height should be same value
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, ROUND_BUTTON_WIDTH_HEIGHT, ROUND_BUTTON_WIDTH_HEIGHT);

//Clip/Clear the other pieces whichever outside the rounded corner
button.clipsToBounds = YES;

//half of the width
button.layer.cornerRadius = ROUND_BUTTON_WIDTH_HEIGHT/2.0f;
button.layer.borderColor=[UIColor redColor].CGColor;
button.layer.borderWidth=2.0f;

[self.view addSubview:button];
```

**Result**

[image]

**Geometry in this concept**

[image]

Comment: Just a update : you need to #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> also.

Comment: @raaz Thanks buddy, if you found anything like that in future, u can edit the code:)

Comment: +1 For adding the `//half of the width` comment. By dividing the button's height/width with 2, you make the `cornerRadius` rounded.

Comment: Anyway to make just the area inside the circle clickable? I'm finding anything inside the original rect is clickable.

Comment: i would suggest you to add one more subview on this button's superview for the tappable position.

Comment: This solution is clean and easy but there is a problem with the button border.  You can see in the screenshot that the border at top is cut.  If you change the border width to 10 (just to put a number) you can see better the behavior.  I think the border is centered and it is not an inside border. Is there any way to draw an inside border instead of a center border?

Comment: I tried the solution and it created a circular button for me.. but when I tried setting a single letter text to it, the text did not show. How can that be rectified?

Comment: You must give enough radius of space to display your text. Otherwise it will be clipped from visibility.

Comment: pressed or unpressed button ?

Comment: If you have highlighted text and normal text as different then consider the big one in width.

Answer (score 30):

Storyboard Option (should apply to Swift or ObjC) -

If you prefer to work in Storyboards, there's another option.

First, set the width and height to be the same value to make a perfect square.
[image]

Second, type in the following attributes.  IMPORTANT- make the value of your layer.cornerRadius half the size of your width.

[image]

Then, when you run the app, your button will be round.

[image]

Comment: Clearly one! According to your way or through code, button width must set equal to its height.

Answer (score 11):

Try this, it worked for me. It will make your button or any view in circular shape only if you have taken it in square i.e width should be equals to height.

```
yourButton.layer.cornerRadius = yourButton.bounds.size.width/2;
```

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode 7.0.0 on IOS 8 this code works perfectly for me.
Provided the length and height of button frame is same.

```
myButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
myButton.layer.cornerRadius = myButton.layer.frame.size.width/2;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let facebookButton = UIButton()
    facebookButton.frame = CGRectMake(30, 200, 150, 150)
    facebookButton.layer.cornerRadius = 75
    facebookButton.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.view.addSubview(facebookButton)
    }
```

** To make round  button you have to give same height and same width for the button and half of the value should be given to corner radius **[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
UIButton *myButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(50,50,30,30);
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonEvent) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sarabjit.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubView:myButton];
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Swift like the answer of 
**Vijay-Apple-Dev.blogspot** :

```
let ROUND_BUTTON_WIDTH_HEIGHT YourButtonWidthToBeSetHere   

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) as UIButton
   button.frame = CGRectMake(160, 100, ROUND_BUTTON_WIDTH_HEIGHT, ROUND_BUTTON_WIDTH_HEIGHT)

   button.layer.cornerRadius = ROUND_BUTTON_WIDTH_HEIGHT / 2.0
   button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
   button.layer.borderWidth = 2.0

   button.setImage(UIImage(named:"TimoonPumba.png"), forState: .Normal)
   button.addTarget(self, action: "roundButtonDidTap", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
   button.clipsToBounds = true

   view.addSubview(button)
}

func roundButtonDidTap() {
   NSLog(@"roundButtonDidTap Method Called");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Use `[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]` to create the button.

Step 2. `CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 30)` is a rectangular shape. Maybe you want to use the size of your image instead, like this:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 0, 0);
frame.size = img.size;
button.frame = frame;
```

Answer (score 0):

a round-rect button with circular image does not satisfy the need of a round Button. Nor even if they are made custom buttons. This is because, This buttons will respond to taps even outside the circular part ( which is a just a .png image ) if it is inside the button size range and not clipped.

The first answer(and only the first one by #vijay-apple-dev) given here is correct. You need to clip the boundary of the button frame in order to stop it responding just outside the image

Answer (score -4):

make a

```
[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

and try to use the corner radius property

```
   button.layer.cornerRadius = button.bounds.size.width/2 / 2.0
```