# Create circle button in iOS7 without images

Tags: ios, uibutton, ios7

I would like to recreate the circular buttons found in the Clock app in iOS7. The buttons are basically circles with different appearance depending on the button states (green border, red border, grey fill).

I could of course achieve this using a simple UIButton with images for the different states.

However I am looking for a solution which draws the circle programmatically, so I can easily change radius, stroke width, etc.

As far as I can see UIButton only allows me to define an UIImage for each state, so I cannot modify the layers per state directly (e.g. provide a layer with cornerRadius). Is there another way?

Comment: Have you considered drawing a circular view and adding tap gestures to it?  Just a thought.

Comment: Yes that would probably work. However I thought to avoid recreating the UIButton functionality. So if there is a solution with a UIButton I would prefer that.

Answer (score 30):

Creating a custom button may be helpful.

in the .h file;

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface CircleLineButton : UIButton

- (void)drawCircleButton:(UIColor *)color;

@end
```

in the .m file;

```
    #import "CircleLineButton.h"

    @interface CircleLineButton ()

    @property (nonatomic, strong) CAShapeLayer *circleLayer;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *color;
    @end

    @implementation CircleLineButton



    - (void)drawCircleButton:(UIColor *)color
    {
        self.color = color;

        [self setTitleColor:color forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        self.circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

        [self.circleLayer setBounds:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, [self bounds].size.width,
                                      [self bounds].size.height)];
        [self.circleLayer setPosition:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX([self bounds]),CGRectGetMidY([self bounds]))];

        UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.frame))];

        [self.circleLayer setPath:[path CGPath]];

        [self.circleLayer setStrokeColor:[color CGColor]];

        [self.circleLayer setLineWidth:2.0f];
        [self.circleLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];

        [[self layer] addSublayer:self.circleLayer];
    }

    - (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted
    {
        if (highlighted)
        {
            self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            [self.circleLayer setFillColor:self.color.CGColor];
        }
        else
        {
            [self.circleLayer setFillColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
            self.titleLabel.textColor = self.color;
        }
    }

@end
```

And in the view controller, call `[self.myCircleButton drawCircleButton:[UIColor myColor]]`

Comment: I found that you needed to use `[self.layer insertSublayer:self.circleLayer atIndex:0];` to insert the circle beneath the title text label, otherwise the button was beneath the solid color when highlighted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6954024/1091402 This is a much superior way. It saves you the trouble of having to deal with hit detection, rotation, auto layout etc. by simply making the button round instead of adding an extra layer to it.

Comment: This works well for me.  Be sure to make your button frame a square or your circle button will be an oval.  You should also indent the path of the circle a couple pixels to account for the lineWidth.  Otherwise you end up with some flat edges on the sides.

Answer (score 11):

There are lot of ways you could accomplish this, for example:

- Use **CAShapedLayer**
- Subclass *UIView* and use the **drawRect:** method to draw a circle
- Just have a square *UIView* and use the **layer.cornerRadius**
  property.

Depending on your needs, something as simple as creating normal UIButton and calling

```
myButton.layer.cornerRadius = myButton.bounds.size.width / 2.0;
```

could work (you'll need to include the **Quartz** Framework)

Comment: Yeah I can draw a circle fine, but how do I connect different circle states (red, green, grey fill) to the UIButton states? Preferably with as little code as possible :-) I could connect several listeners and show/hide the circles accordingly, but that feels a bit overkill.

Comment: I think the best course of action would be to create a normal UIButton, and add a CAShapedLayer (with circle shape) as the *mask* property of that button's layer.

Comment: That would give me a general circular appearance, but I would not be able to define different border/fill colors for each button state, right? I can only provide a UIImage per state via setBackgroundImage:forState:

Answer (score 4):

The pattern I've used to achieve this kind of thing is:

Subclass `UIButton` and implement `drawRect` to draw the button as you want, customising colours based on the `selected` and `highlighted` properties of the button.

Then override `setSelected` and `setHighlighted` to force redraws like so:

```
-(void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted {
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add this code

```
imagePreview.layer.cornerRadius = (imagePreview.bounds.size.height/2);
```

where imagePreview is  UIview/UIimageview/UIButton

don't forget to add

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: This is the simplest and easiest solution.  Worked well for me, and super-quick to implement.

Answer (score 4):

Solution with a swift Extension :

```
extension UIView{
    func asCircle(){
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2;
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Just call

```
myView.asCircle()
```

Can work with any type of view, not only a button

Comment: Minor Correction: `self.frame.size.width`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this control, it's subclass from UIButton.
https://github.com/alvaromb/AMBCircularButton

Answer (score 0):

I think it work good.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(.Custom) as UIButton
    button.frame = CGRectMake(160, 100, 50, 50)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.width
    button.setImage(UIImage(named:"thumbsUp.png"), forState: .Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "thumbsUpButtonPressed", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    view.addSubview(button)
}

func thumbsUpButtonPressed() {
    println("thumbs up button pressed")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. In storyboard, Make square UIButton (eg. 100 * 100 )
2. Link outlet (eg. @property (Strong, nonatomic) UIButton IBOutlet * myButton; )
3. In your code write this:
   **self.myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 50;** 
   // 50 is half of square's length of one side.