# UIImage with rounded borders like in contacts

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to make an `UITableView` that in every cell I can see an image like in profile picture in contacts .

I made an `UIView` that makes custom drawings , in draw rect , it works FINE in iPhone 5c
but it kills iPhone 4 and iPhone4s when I scrolling the table view

here is what I have done :

```
// _image is iVar

// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIColor *patternRed = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[self imageWithImage:_image scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width,self.frame.size.height)]];//recale image to self bounds 
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 0.0);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, patternRed.CGColor);
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rect);
    CGContextDrawPath(context, kCGPathFill); // Or kCGPathFill //kCGPathFillStroke
}

- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    // In next line, pass 0.0 to use the current device's pixel scaling factor (and thus account for Retina resolution).
    // Pass 1.0 to force exact pixel size.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

I am not good in this Graphics contexts
maybe I have done something wrong :(

is there any way to speed up the process ?

Comment: please refer my answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6954024/675170

Comment: @Vijay-Apple-Dev.blogspot.com  Is making it with `layers` makes the things faster ?

Comment: No need to override drawRect method you can use cornerRadius property of layer.

Comment: I tried the solution with layers , it seems to be even slower :(

Answer (score 1):

first import this into your class  `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`
and then add the following method into your class

```
    -(UIImageView * )createRoundedImageview:(UIImageView*)imageView
    {
        //  this works in the case of width and height of image view are same
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width/2.0; //or imageView.frame.size.height/2.0
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        return imageView;
    }
```

and then call where ever you want a rounded image like..

```
UIImageView * yourImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithframe:CGRectMake(100,150,200,200)];
yourImageView.image = [UIImage ImageNamed:@"yourimageName"];
yourImageView = [self createRoundedImageview: yourImageView];
[self.view addSubView: yourImageView];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
button.clipsToBounds = YES;
button.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0f
button.layer.borderColor=[UIColor <colorname>].CGColor;
button.layer.borderWidth=2.0f; //
```

the above code works for you

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to draw it yourself like this; you can use a standard `UIImageView` and set its `cornerRadius` to give it the circular effect (setting it to `edgeLength / 2` will create a perfect circle).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to have rounded borders.

```
newImage.layer.cornerRadius = newImage.frame.size.width / 2.0;
newImage.clipsToBounds = YES;
newImage.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
```

The code using the cornerRadius property of the imageview where it will set the radius equals  width of image by 2.0.
The next statement allows you to clip the image.
Third step is optional.