# Constraining to center horizontally & vertically in superview prevents me from changing the frame

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, autolayout

I have a `UIButton` within a `UIView` with two constraints. Both constraints were set in Interface Builder so that the `UIButton` is centered vertically and horizontally in its superview.

I wanted to add a border to the `UIButton` and make it rounded. Having followed an [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6954024/1815321) I was able to get the button partially rounded.

[image: Simi-rounded button]

For some reason though, the button is not really round. I assume this is because of my height & width not being equal to each other. Each time I set the width/height of the button to be equal, the autolayout constraints reset it back to 40x34.

I am using the following code to create the rounded button.

```
self.startButton.clipsToBounds = true
self.startButton.layer.cornerRadius = self.startButton.frame.height / 2
self.startButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
self.startButton.layer.borderColor = self.view.tintColor.CGColor
self.startButton.layer.shadowRadius = 6.0
self.startButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
self.startButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 3.0)
self.startButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.65
```

Why does having my button centered vertically and horizontally prevent me from changing its size? I don't understand why I can't set the size of the button and have the constraints re-center it based on the size values I assign to it.

### Edit

I have moved the code in to the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and then modified the constraints so that both the height and width are constrained to 40x40.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.startButton.clipsToBounds = true
    self.startButton.titleLabel?.text = "Start"
    self.startButton.layer.cornerRadius = self.startButton.frame.height / 2
    self.startButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
    self.startButton.layer.borderColor = self.view.tintColor.CGColor
    self.startButton.layer.shadowRadius = 6.0
    self.startButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    self.startButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 3.0)
    self.startButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.65
}
```

This partially solves my problem; not fully though. If I do not assign a value to the `titleLabel`, then the button is a proper round button.

[image: Round button]

However, if I assign a value to the `titleLabel`, the button becomes a rounded rect and is not a circle.

[image: Rounded Rect]

The text does not appear in the button though, which confuses me. I need to have the button be a circle, scaling to fit the content it has as well. My button type is set to `Custom`. I don't know if that has any effect on this as well.

#### Edit 2

After doing some testing, I discovered i was setting the edge insets to the button. Once I removed the following:

```
self.startButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 25, left: 25, bottom: 25, right: 25)
```

I got the desired effect with @Leo's answer.

[image: Rounded arrow button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add constraints about height & width of your button.

Either fixed width & height,or aspect radio is ok.

If you use aspect radio,set up the corner radius in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`