# how to make radio button and checkbox button in iphone?

Tags: iphone

Can anybody tell me the code to make radio button and checkbox button in iphone.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650131/checkbox-in-iphone-application) for checkbox Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662646/radio-button-in-iphone-app) for radiobutton

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really want to provide the users with a non-standard experience and invent your own controls (which are likely to not be so fine-tuned as those provided out-of-the-box), i would go with **UISwitch** instead of checkbox and **UIPickerView** instead of a radiobutton(s)

Answer (score 0):

@Nitin in these cases you have to use the images in `UIImageView` for checked or unchecked....basically they are images or one more procedure is to use the custom `UIButton` and give them images accordingly to situation

Comment: Why do you want to use an UIImageView here ?

Comment: @DarkDust i had done  the same procedure in my app...that's why i suggest

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it manually by using UIButtons:

Checkbox: create two images, assign one via `setImage:forState:` with state `UIControlStateNormal`, the other with state `UIControlStateSelected`. Then you can toggle the images simply by setting the button's `selected` property to NO or YES.

Radiobox: same as with checkbox, but you have to keep track of the other radioboxes (e.g. via an array) and set `foo.selected = NO` for all the not-selected checkboxes.