# Using radio buttons in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, xcode

How do I a use radio  button in an iPhone app? Should I load any image instead of button image?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662646/radio-button-in-iphone-app

Answer (score 4):

A fairly standard replacement for radio buttons on iOS is a "picker". An alternative, if you have a large number of potential choices, is to use a static list under a button, and allow only one of the items to be selected and checkmarked.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a custom button & change its image on button click

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the `UISegmentedControl`.  It functions basically as a radio button for up to ~4 options.  There's no maximum limit AFAIK, but any more than 4 is somewhat difficult visually.

Answer (score 1):

Try `DLRadioButton`, the best Radio Button control for iOS. It is highly customizable, you can also use you own image as selection indicator. It is available through Cocoapods `pod 'DLRadioButton', '~> 1.4'` and at [GitHub](https://github.com/DavydLiu/DLRadioButton).

Screenshot for your reference.

[image: iOS Radio Button Control]