# Why did Apple not include radio buttons in Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone

I realized that people have been implementing their own UIButton derivates to create radio buttons on iPhone, as [this blog post](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-uibutton-tutorial-radio-buttons/) shows.

This [question's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662646/radio-button-in-iphone-app) states you can use *Picker Views* or *Grouped Table views with a check mark*, but it seems like a poor man's solution to me. Hence, my question: what is Apple's likely reasoning?

- Are radio buttons a bad UI solution for touch interfaces?
- Is it so rarely used that it's not worth cluttering IB with?

Another reason I don't quite see, maybe? I believe it's important to find this out, because if Apple thinks radio buttons suck, I'd rather not use them, and rethink my interface whenever I "believe" I should use one...

Comment: "Are radio buttons a bad UI solution for touch interfaces?" Radio buttons are so tiny; even if you increase their hit size, people are going to think they're hard to press just by looking at them. Anyway, you'll still find radio buttons in web apps.

Comment: Well, come to think of it, I have used radio buttons on Android, and they are not tiny, nor feel tiny. They do feel somehow clunky imho, but I could not say why...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually seeing it with a different angle, Apple has neither provided Radio buttons or even Check Box and maybe not because they think that it is a bad UI solution. But instead they've empowered the UIButton control very much that we can configure it as a Radio button or a check box or a switch or anything else with few lines of code. 
A UIButton object can be configured and designed in various ways. We've seen various apps using the UIButton very creatively. I personally like the versatility of UIButton rather than Apple directly providing the radio button and Check box to drag and drop it in the interface.

Answer (score 2):

Radio buttons are a bad UI solution if they are poorly implemented. i.e. too small to reliably work with touches - which is why it's usually better to either use a toolbar or segmented control of options or a tableview of options.

Comment: In one of my applications, I have used a two-icon button with male and female gender symbols to allow the user to pick a gender. I now realize it is actually a radio button in disguise. Should I have used in your opinion a segmented control instead?

Comment: I said "usually". In your instance, I would maybe say no - I'd have to see the design to say for sure though. I think the key thing is usability including ensuring the buttons are big enough.